# Scala Lift few https questions

Tags: scala, https, lift

I have few questions about https in Scala Lift:

How can I set for my web application use only https protocol?

Must I rewrite some code for existing application for using https?

Is request response cycle changes or there is no any differents?

Where to find good scala lift open source project using https or just to see advanced use of framework?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTTPS needs to be enabled in your servlet container, such as Jetty or Tomcat. It doesn't have much to do with your web application. Then you need to tell the servlet container to use HTTPS for some or all pages in the deployment descriptor. This is what your web.xml file will look like:

```
<web-app>
    . . .
    <security-constraint>
        . . .
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
```